# Message queue in java

Tags: java, message-queue, high-availability

I am looking for a message queue system in java which has following properties.

- High availability/No single point of failure (Ability to use cassandra as backend)
- Ensure "deliver once and exactly" once messaging.
- No arbitary limits on message size (able to handle messages upwards of 1MB in size)

Comment: What have you considered so far?  Have you tried Googling JMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides my favorite, [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (WAS MQ is bloated and expensive):

- I like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual)
- [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/)-based: [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/)

> **EDIT:**
>   I forgot to mention another high throughput pub-sub from Apache (developed from the ground-up to be distributed):
>
> - [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/)
>   Kafka will soon get exactly-once semantics (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging))
>
> And of course:
>
> - [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.rabbitmq.com or you can create by yourself with Hazelcast

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a MQ system that provides Java API for put/get messages. You can consider IBM WebSphere MQ.